# Get Package Name from APK-comamnd

Tags: android

Hi I have a android mobile. I want to know the .apk file name of the package being installed on my phone.

I want the command which will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pm list packages -f
```

This command will give you the exact path of the apk related to the installed package.

If you want apk of a certain package then apply grep to the output like this:

```
pm list packages -f | grep "package.name"
```